# Finding unique values in a record set

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array of zipcodes. This is just an example for you to have a clue what I am asking.

zipcodes = [53081, 53083, 54935, 53711, 54935, 53081, 57322, 53083, 53711];

How can I loop through the array only once to output only the unique zipcodes as a HTML list? (53081, 53083, 54935, 53711, 53722)

**My code below opens a record set from another file without knowing how many unique zip codes there are. I have it where it outputs all of them.**

**I am only suppose to output the unique zip codes as a list in HTML.**

```
function zips() {
    "use strict";

    var zipCodeRecords;
    var zipCode;
    var uniqueZips;
    var output;

    uniqueZips = "";

    // get the HTML output tag to add list
    output = document.getElementById("outputDiv");

    // open zipcode records
    zipCodeRecords = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();

    while(zipCodeRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        zipCode = zipCodeRecords.getSampleZipCode();

        uniqueZips += "<li>" + zipCode + "</li>";
    }

    output.innerHTML = uniqueZips;

}
```

Comment: If I'm Not Wrong, Your Answer Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates.

If I'm Right Then POSSIBLE DUPLICATE.

Comment: @Swaggerboy correct, very elegant solution as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way is to add each element as a key in an object.

If the same key is defined more than once, it will not increase the number of keys (no duplicates)

```js
var zipcodes = [53081, 53083, 54935, 53711, 54935, 53081, 57322, 53083, 53711];
var uinque = {};

zipcodes.map(function(z){ uinque[z]=z; });

console.log(Object.keys(uinque));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` by passing the current item, index and the array itself. Then return items only if the index of current item is equal to the current index.

```js
var zipcodes = [53081, 53083, 54935, 53711, 54935, 53081, 57322, 53083, 53711];

var res = zipcodes.filter((v, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) === idx);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function zips() {
    "use strict";

    var zipCodeRecords;
    var zipCode;
    var uniqueZips;
    var output;

    uniqueZips = "";

    // get the HTML output tag to add list
    output = document.getElementById("outputDiv");

    // open zipcode records
    zipCodeRecords = openZipCodeStudyRecordSet();

    zipcodesList = [];
    while(zipCodeRecords.readNextRecord()) {
        zipCode = zipCodeRecords.getSampleZipCode();
   if(zipcodesList.indexOf(zipCode )== -1){
        zipcodesList [] = zipCode
        uniqueZips += "<li>" + zipCode + "</li>";
      }

    }

    output.innerHTML = uniqueZips;

}
```

//This should help